# Cloud Content Management Systems

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, mobile, content-management-system, cloud-hosting

In search of a 'Cloud Content Management System' like http://osmek.com/,
I could not find a single other **CCMS** that does what I want it to do :)

Basically, what I need is content management without a website frontend attached.
Just basic storage of data, documents, images, etc. etc. with a simple API to access, like `Osmek`. Just `NoSQL` or `SQL` based services won't do, because there can be images or documents attached. And, ofcourse, I'd like to have a backend to manage the data (like a typical CMS does) without writing a backend myself (if it's just the service)

`Osmek` is great, and it works most awesome in conjunction with `Actionscript 3`, but I'm just looking / searching for alternatives (if there even are any yet).

I need this form of hosted content management for content-manageing a mobile application.
So the question is: Is there anything else out there that does the same as `osmek` that you know of? OR, how do you manage application specific content?

**Thanks!**

Comment: In the meanwhile, i've found Parse, which is exactly the kind of service i was trying to point at: https://www.parse.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'd encourage you to take a look at **Cloud CMS** (http://www.cloudcms.com).

**Cloud CMS** is a JSON content management (CMS) platform built on top of MongoDB with a REST API and drivers for a variety of languages.  You just drop in a driver and call methods to query, create, update and delete content.

The platform provides everything you need to power the back-end for mobile and HTML5 applications - from managing your content to managing users and groups, credentials, security tokens (OAuth2), Git-like collaborative workspaces, real-time analytics, activities, data transformations and more.

Everything runs in the cloud on an elastic back-end.  It's probably more akin to Parse than a traditional CMS.  You just make calls to the APIs.  We keep the costs low by letting you only pay for what you use (almost like a utility).  You just pay for storage and data transfer.

**Disclaimer**: I'm one of the founders of Cloud CMS.  So I'm a pretty lousy reference in terms of its objective value. However, a couple of us worked at traditional "ECM" companies in the past and we think we've built something that puts a genuine beating on those guys.

Comment: ya `Cloud CMS` is really good and its what I was looking for. Thanks :-)